# Delete all 'nohup.out' within a directory recursively

Tags: command-line, files, rm, recursive

How can I delete all 'nohup.out' files within a directory recursively from my terminal? I'm using CentOS.

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple files called `nohup.out` in subdirectories of one directory? If that's the case, try the following command: `find . -name nohup.out -exec rm {} +`.

Comment: You mean "within a directory?" What is the problem with `rm nohup.out*`?

Comment: Your question is somehow unclear, because there can't be more than one file with the particular name in one directory.

Comment: @RistoSalminen multiple nohup.out within one directory would not be good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can't be multiple files named `nohup.out` in a single directory, so I assume you mean that you want to remove it recursively:

```
find . -name nohup.out -exec rm {} +
```

If you are using GNU find, you can use `-delete`:

```
find . -name nohup.out -delete
```

In bash4+, you can also use `globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
rm -- **/nohup.out
```

Note, however, that `globstar` traverses symlinks when descending the directory tree, and may break if the length of the file list exceeds the limit on the size of arguments.